# why won't background change in firefox but it will in ie

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link id="csslink" href="Handler.ashx" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Blue" />
        <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Red" />
    </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pageDefault = {
            btn1: document.getElementById('Button1'),
            btn2: document.getElementById('Button2'),
            csslink: document.getElementById('csslink'),
            init: function() {
                this.btn1.onclick = function() {
                    pageDefault.csslink.href = "Handler.ashx?id=1";
                }
                this.btn2.onclick = function() {
                    pageDefault.csslink.href = "Handler.ashx?id=2";
                }
            }
        }
        pageDefault.init();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the ashx ProcessRequest

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        var id = context.Request.QueryString["id"];

        if (id == "1")
        {

            context.Response.Write(@"
body
{
  background: Blue;
}  

");
        }
        else if (id == "2")
        {
            context.Response.Write(@"
body
{
  background: Red;
}  

");
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 context.Response.ContentType = "text/css";
```

Comment: Thanks for the eyes! Thanks all for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
body
{
    /* Red */
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

body
{
    /* Blue */
    background-color: #0c00ff;
}
```

Comment: i changed the attribute to background-color but still no luck as well as to hex color

Comment: This works for me in Firefox so it may be a code issue? Can you display the source generated by your code? http://jsfiddle.net/REXZM/

Comment: where do i go to get that for you

Comment: View source in the browser and just copy/paste the relevant part(s) into the question. This should give us a clue into what's happening. If it's a JavaScript issue, I'll let someone more qualified attempt an answer.

Comment: That's what I posted up on the paste bin